# How to RadioButton get selected

Tags: java, android, radio-button, android-radiogroup

I have an API and there is a value of broadcast and the options are public, private, logged in and unlisted. I want a radiobutton to be selected itself as public if broadcast is public.

**This is my XML code:**

```
<TextView
    android:textColor="#060606"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:text="Broadcast Options"
    android:id="@+id/broadcast_head"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/radio_group_broadcast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Public"
            android:id="@+id/radio_button_public"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <RadioButton
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Private"
            android:id="@+id/radio_button_private"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <RadioButton
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Unlisted"
            android:id="@+id/radio_button_unlisted"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <RadioButton
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Logged Only"
            android:id="@+id/radio_button_logged_only"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RadioGroup>
</TextView>
```

**and this is my Java code;
I don't know whether this code is correct or not.**

```
rbPub = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_button_public);
rbPri = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_button_private);
rbUnl = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_button_unlisted);
rbOnl = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_button_logged_only);

radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group_broadcast);
VideoDetail videoDetailBroadcast = null; //this is the problem, can't fix(null)
if (videoDetailBroadcast.isPublic()) {
    rbPub.setChecked(true);
}
else if (videoDetailBroadcast.isPrivate()) {
    rbPri.setChecked(true);
}
else if (videoDetailBroadcast.isUnlisted()) {
        rbUnl.setChecked(true);
    }
else if (videoDetailBroadcast.isLoggedOnly()) {
        rbOnl.setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: Is there a `BroadcastReceiver` set up somewhere? What is `VideoDetail` and how/where do you expect the value to change?

Answer (score 0):

You should should initialize videoDetailBroadcast that way : `VideoDetail videoDetailBroadcast = new VideoDetail()`